# How to return the position (Index) of an element after reshaping from 1D to 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 1d numpy array like `p=array([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])`

In my work, I need to change it to 2d array like

```
p_reshape = array([[1,2,3], 
                   [4,5,6],
                   [6,7,8],
                   [9,10,11]])
```

I have other function which returns the position of the element i in p matrix (1d) say p(i)

Now I want to know the position of the p(i) in the 2d matrix p_reshape after convert it.

The below show the code for converting from 1d to 2d:

```
row=300
col=500
size=row*col
p=np.ones((size))
p_reshape=np.reshape((row,size))
```

I hope I express my idea well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `numpy.unravel_index`

```
In [3]: import numpy as np
In [4]: p = np.array([ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

In [5]: p_reshape = p.reshape(4,3)

In [6]: p_reshape
Out[6]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

In [7]: np.unravel_index(5, p_reshape.shape)
Out[7]: (1, 2)
```

Comment: I didn't know NumPy provided a way to do this natively -- nicer than my way of doing it by hand. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can just use:

```
p_reshape[i // ncols, i % ncols]
```

can't you?

```
p = np.arange(1,13)
p_reshape = p.reshape((4,3))
ncols = p_reshape.shape[1]
all(p_reshape[i // ncols, i % ncols] == p[i] for i in range(p.size))

True
```